# Authlogic - Authentication via basic HTTP authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I want to use "authenticate_ with_ http_ basic"  but I just can not get it
working.

In my RoR app Authlogic is working fine and I'm using User Sessions for that. While keeping that method as it is now i need to use authenticate_with_http_basic.I have a iPhone SDK app and now I need to fetch some products from my webapp and display as list. So I'm assuming that i need to send the request to my webapp like this; http://username:password@192.168.1.9/products/

So my question is to validate this username and password and what I need to do to my UserSession Controller?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to do anything with `UserSessionController`, since that controller would only handle login form submit and logout.

Authlogic and `authenticate_with_http_basic` is irrelevant to each other. If you want to authenticate via HTTP basic, you just need to create a method to authenticate using method provided by Rails, and put that method on the `before_filter`. By logging in via HTTP authentication, I assume that the username and password should be mandatory for every request.

So finally, your `ProductsController` would be something like this

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_via_http_basic

  # In case you have some method to redirect user to login page, skip it
  skip_before_filter :require_authentication

  ...

  protected

  def authenticate_via_http_basic
    unless current_user
      authenticate_with_http_basic do |username, password|
        if user = User.find_by_username(username)
          user.valid_password?(password)
        else
          false
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hi, This is working now. but after integrating the http_basic_athentication on the controller, UserSession based authentication is not working now. I always get the http_basic_athentication Login prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication via HTTP Auth is now integrated into AuthLogic, and it is enabled by default.

Comment: I see this method authenticate_with_http_basic(&block) in the method list of the docs, but I can't seem to figure out how to use it.  What would a solution that uses the integrated Authentication via HTTP Auth look like versus the solution that Sikachu provided?